# Imagen no cargada en JLabel Java

Tags: java, imagen, jlabel

No me carga las imágenes en un `**JLabel**` por ninguno de los siguientes 3 métodos.

**Primer método:**

```
 label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".jpg"));
```

**Segundo método:**

```
 File archivo_bandera = new File("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".jpg");
 bandera = ImageIO.read(archivo_bandera);
 System.out.println("Imagen cargada.");
 label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bandera));
```

**Tercer método** (en este caso, me carga la imagen pero en blanco y negro, cuando está en color):

```
  URL url_foto = this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".jpg");
  ImageIcon ico_foto = new ImageIcon(url_foto);
  label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ico_foto.getImage().getScaledInstance(label_foto.getWidth(), label_foto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Método completo:**

```
private void combo_comunidadesItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                   
        //Guardamos en una variable string el valor seleccionado del combo_comunidades.
        String comunidad = (String) combo_comunidades.getSelectedItem();
        String capital = null;
        //Si el index del combo_comunidades es cero, NO existe comunidad: deshabilitamos.
        if(combo_comunidades.getSelectedIndex()==0) {
            combo_provincias.setEnabled(false);
            textfield_capital.setEnabled(false);
            label_foto.setEnabled(false);
        }else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            //Habilitamos.
            combo_provincias.setEnabled(true);
            textfield_capital.setEnabled(true);

            //Creamos un ArrayList de String para las provincias.
            ArrayList<String> provincias = new ArrayList<String>();
            //Devolvemos las provincias dada una comunidad.
            provincias = Conexiones.cargar_provincias(comunidad);

            //Recorremos el ArrayList de provincias.
            Iterator<String> i = provincias.iterator();
            //Limpiamos los valores anteriores del combo_provincias.
            combo_provincias.removeAllItems();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                //Añadimos a los items con cada provincia.
                combo_provincias.addItem(i.next());
            }

            //Devolvemos las provicinas dada una comunidad.
            capital = Conexiones.capital_de_comunidad(comunidad);
            textfield_capital.setText(capital);

            //Ponemos la foto de la comunidad seleccionada.
            label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".jpg"));

            try {
                File archivo_bandera = new File("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".jpg");
                bandera = ImageIO.read(archivo_bandera);
                System.out.println("Imagen cargada.");
                label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bandera));

                /*URL url_foto = this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/"+comunidad+".jpg");
                ImageIcon ico_foto = new ImageIcon(url_foto);
                label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ico_foto.getImage().getScaledInstance(label_foto.getWidth()-10, label_foto.getHeight()-10, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));   
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Combobox_Anidado.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

¿Por qué no me carga las imágenes? Todas tienen una extensión .jpg y están en la carpeta "src/imagenes".

Answer (score 0):

Si la ruta como dices esta en src/imagenes debes escribir la ruta de este modo:

`label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/imagenes/comunidad.jpg));`

Comment: No funciona de esa manera. Me carga la imagen, sí, pero en blanco y negro transparente cuando la foto original está en color. Adjunté una imagen explicatoria. @JavAnubis